# Accessing Class objects to compare with global variables

Tags: c++, class, methods

Im making a text store menu. I have a basic weapon class with a string for name and weapon sound, a bool for if you already own the item or not and a double for the price.

I'm trying to compare the double price in the class to the global variable p_balance (players balance) to 
check if the player can afford the item

Here's the class

```
class Weapon
{
public:
    string name, sound;
    bool owned = false;
    double price;

public:

    Weapon() //Default Constructor
    {
        name = "name";
        sound = "sound";
        owned = owned;
        price = 0;

    }

    Weapon(string i_name, string i_sound, bool i_owned, double i_price)//Constructor
    {
        name = i_name;
        sound = i_sound;
        owned = i_owned;
        price = i_price;

        void displayItems();
        {
            cout << name << " - " << price << "g." << endl;
        }


    }

};
```

(i know i know i should switch Weapon Weapons[i] to Weapon weapons[i] to make my life easier)

And here's my most recent attempt at accessing it

```
while (p_balance < Weapons[0].getPrice()) // Not enough gold
                {
                    cout << "Sorry, it seems you don't have enough gold." << endl;
                    goto MainMenu;
                }
```

I had tried to make a method within the class to get the price but that didnt work out, but thats why its calling on a method that doesnt exist

I've also toyed around with if loops but the were getting messy and displaying more info than i liked
After the owner money check, i have it perform a ownership check and check if something equipped to that items slot, but when I used nested if statements it displayed the result of all of them even if the first if (price) was failed so I figured maybe a while statement?

I'm not looking for the answer cause I want to learn but last time I posted here I got some great hints that really helped me out and I'm hitting the point of frustration with this so I figured I'd ask for help!

EDIT:

I took what you guys said into account and went back to the pseudo.
I'm quite pleased with how it is now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int p_choice;
double p_balance = 125;

//Simple Weapon Class
class Weapon
{
public:
    int slot;
    string name, sound;
    bool owned = false;
    double price;



public:

    Weapon() //Default Constructor
    {
        slot = 0;
        name = "name";
        sound = "sound";
        owned = owned;
        price = 0;


    }

    Weapon(int i_slot, string i_name, string i_sound, bool i_owned, double i_price)//Constructor
    {
        slot = i_slot;
        name = i_name;
        sound = i_sound;
        owned = i_owned;
        price = i_price;

        double* p_ptr;
        p_ptr = &price;

        void displayItems();
        {
            int x = 0;

            cout << slot << " - " <<  name << " - " << price << "g." << endl;
        }

    }
};


int main()
{

    int p_selection;
    bool hasWeapon, offHand, inStore;
    hasWeapon = false;
    offHand = false;
    inStore = true;

//Weapon Array
    cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
    Weapon Weapons[6];
    Weapons[0] = Weapon(1, "Great Sword of Greatening", "Tssng", false, 50);
    Weapons[1] = Weapon(2, "Claw", "Thwack", false, 10);
    Weapons[2] = Weapon(3, "Silent Pea-shooter", "Pew Pew", false, 15);
    Weapons[3] = Weapon(4, "Loudening Silencer Attachment", "...", false, 5);
    Weapons[4] = Weapon(5, "Tiger-Repelling Rock ", "Meooowraaarah", false, 25);
    Weapons[5] = Weapon(6, "The Stick of Truth", "How do you kill that which has no life", false, 100);
    cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Welcome to my store, traveller!" << endl;
    cout << "How can I help you?" << endl;

//Menu

    do
    {


        cout << "1. Buy" << endl;
        cout << "2. Check Balance" << endl;
        cout << "3. Exit" << endl;

        cin >> p_choice;
        if (p_choice == 1)
        {

//Ask player which weapon the want to buy

            cout << "Which item are you interested in?" << endl;
            cout << "(Choose using 1-6)" << endl;
            cin >> p_selection;
            if (p_selection >= 1 && p_selection <= 6)
            {
                int i_choice = p_selection - 1;// Take one off the choice so it corresponds correctly to the object in the array
                if (Weapons[i_choice].owned == false && p_balance >= Weapons[p_selection].price)// check if item is owned/can be bought
                {
                    if (hasWeapon == false)// flip "Slot" flag
                    {
                        hasWeapon = true;
                    }

                    Weapons[i_choice].owned = true;// flip ownership flag
                    p_balance = p_balance - Weapons[i_choice].price; // update balance

                    cout << "Good eye, that's a fine item! Enjoy your " << Weapons[i_choice].name << endl;

                }
                else if (Weapons[i_choice].price > p_balance)
                {
                    cout << "Seems you're a little short on gold..." << endl;

                }
                else if (Weapons[i_choice].owned == true)
                {
                    cout << "Seems you don't know how to dual wield, why don't you pick something else." << endl;

                }



            }
        }

// Check Balance
        if (p_choice == 2)
        {   
            cout << "Your balance is: " << p_balance << "g." << endl;
        }

// Leave
        if (p_choice == 3 && inStore == true)
        {
            cout << "Thanks for stopping by! Good luck out there!" << endl;
            inStore = false;

        }
        else if (p_choice == 3 && hasWeapon == false)
        {
            cout << "You're gonna want a weapon out there, traveller" << endl;
        }
    } while (inStore == true);



//Scenario
    bool scenario = true;

    cout << "Inventory" << endl;
    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
    {
        if (Weapons[x].owned == true)
        {
            //convey slot
            cout << "Press " << Weapons[x].slot << " to use your " << Weapons[x].name << endl;
            cin >> p_choice;
        }

    }
    do
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 1; y++)
        {
            int use = p_choice - 1;

            if (Weapons[use].owned == true)
            {

                cout << Weapons[use].sound << endl;

            }

        }
    } while (scenario == true);




    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Only issue is it plays the "sound" nonstop, that for loop was an attempt to have it run 1 time lol

Comment: Search your favorite C++ reference for "initialization lists".

Comment: I recommend you change your design to avoid `goto`.  The `goto` statement without proper discipline can invoke spaghetti code and unwanted behavior.

Comment: Looks like you need to spend more time *designing* your program than coding.   For example, you need to determine where you need a loop versus using a conditional statement.

Comment: 1. You are declaring/defining a function within the definition of a constructor.
2. You put an extra semi-colon between the declaration and definition of "displayItems()".

Comment: Where is the global variable "p_balance" declared? if it is declared in a different file, you need to search the usage of "extern".

Comment: "i know i should switch Weapon Weapons[i] to Weapon weapons[i] ": so why don't you do it? :)

Comment: "I had tried to make a method within the class to get the price but that didnt work out, but thats why its calling on a method that doesnt exist": please elaborate... Show the code you have tried. This is also a good read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Completely re hauled the main loop. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final final product

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int p_choice;
double p_balance = 125;

//Simple Weapon Class
class Weapon
{
public:
    int slot, durability;
    string name, sound;
    bool owned = false;
    double price;



public:

    Weapon() //Default Constructor
    {
        slot = 0;
        name = "name";
        sound = "sound";
        owned = owned;
        price = 0;
        durability = 0;


    }

    Weapon(int i_slot, string i_name, string i_sound, bool i_owned, double i_price, int i_durability)//Constructor
    {
        slot = i_slot;
        name = i_name;
        sound = i_sound;
        owned = i_owned;
        price = i_price;
        durability = i_durability;

        void displayItems();
        {
            int x = 0;

            cout << slot << " - " << name << " - " << price << "g." << endl;
        }

    }
};


int main()
{

    int p_selection;
    bool hasWeapon, offHand, inStore;
    hasWeapon = false;
    offHand = false;
    inStore = true;

    //Weapon Array
    cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "For Sale:" << endl;
    Weapon Weapons[6];
    Weapons[0] = Weapon(1, "Great Sword of Greatening", "Tssng", false, 50, 25);
    Weapons[1] = Weapon(2, "Claw", "Thwack", false, 10, 15);
    Weapons[2] = Weapon(3, "Silent Pea-shooter", "Pew Pew", false, 15, 20);
    Weapons[3] = Weapon(4, "Loudening Silencer Attachment", "...", false, 5, 5);
    Weapons[4] = Weapon(5, "Tiger-Repelling Rock ", "Meooowraaarah", false, 25, 30);
    Weapons[5] = Weapon(6, "The Stick of Truth", "How do you kill that which has no life", false, 100, 50);
    cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Welcome to my store, traveller!" << endl;
    cout << "How can I help you?" << endl;

    //Menu

    do
    {


        cout << "1. Buy" << endl;
        cout << "2. Check Balance" << endl;
        cout << "3. Exit" << endl;


        cin >> p_choice;
        if (p_choice == 1)
        {

            //Ask player which weapon the want to buy

            cout << "Which item are you interested in?" << endl;
            cout << "(Choose using 1-6)" << endl;
            cin >> p_selection;
            if (p_selection >= 1 && p_selection <= 6)
            {
                int i_choice = p_selection - 1;// Take one off the choice so it corresponds correctly to the object in the array
                if (Weapons[i_choice].owned == false && p_balance >= Weapons[p_selection].price)// check if item is owned/can be bought
                {
                    if (hasWeapon == false)// flip weapon flag
                    {
                        hasWeapon = true;
                    }

                    Weapons[i_choice].owned = true;// flip ownership flag
                    p_balance = p_balance - Weapons[i_choice].price; // update balance

                    cout << "Good eye, that's a fine item! Enjoy your " << Weapons[i_choice].name << endl;

                }
                else if (Weapons[i_choice].price > p_balance)
                {
                    cout << "Seems you're a little short on gold..." << endl;

                }
                else if (Weapons[i_choice].owned == true)
                {
                    cout << "Seems you don't know how to dual wield, why don't you pick something else." << endl;
                    cout << "(You already own this item)" << endl;

                }




            }
        }

        // Check Balance
        if (p_choice == 2)
        {
            cout << "Your balance is: " << p_balance << "g." << endl;
        }

        // Leave
        if (p_choice == 3 && inStore == true)
        {
            cout << "Thanks for stopping by! Good luck out there!" << endl;
            inStore = false;

        }
        else if (p_choice == 3 && hasWeapon == false)
        {
            cout << "You're gonna want a weapon out there, traveller" << endl;
        }
    } while (inStore == true);



    //Scenario
    bool scenario, equipped;
    int attack, equip, choose;

    equipped = false;
    scenario = true;

    do
    {

    Equip:
        cout << "----------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "                Inventory" << endl;
        for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
        {
            if (Weapons[x].owned == true)
            {
                //convey slot and display equippable items
                cout << Weapons[x].slot << " - " << Weapons[x].name << " - Uses Left: " << Weapons[x].durability << endl;

            }

        }
        cout << "----------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "What would you like to equip? (Select using the given number + Enter)" << endl;
        cout << "(Press 9 to quit)" << endl;
        cin >> choose;
        equip = choose - 1;
        if (choose == 9)
        {
            scenario = false;
        }
        else if (Weapons[equip].owned == true)
        {
            int action;
            cout << "You have equipped " << Weapons[equip].name << endl;
        Action:
            cout << "Press 1 and Enter to use." << endl;
            cout << "Press 2 and Enter to equip a new item" << endl;
            cout << "Press 3 and Enter to go home" << endl;
            cin >> action;


            if (Weapons[equip].durability <= 0)// cant use broken items
            {
                cout << "That item appears to have broken!" << endl;

            }
            else if (action == 1 && Weapons[equip].durability >= 0)// attack and durability check
            {
                cout << Weapons[equip].sound << endl;
                cout << endl;
                Weapons[equip].durability--;// durability decrement
                goto Action;

            }
            else if (action == 2)// change equip
            {
                goto Equip;
            }
            else if (action == 3)// exit
            {
                scenario = false;
            }

        }


    } while (scenario == true);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "I wish you a safe journey home, traveller." << endl;



    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Thanks again for the guidance.